# Payment gateway integration of ccavenue in android

Tags: php, android, ccavenue

I have implemented using php kit and connected android activity with html page with the help of webview. Now how to do i pass the value to the html page and make it in readable format bt cannot edit it???

`enter code here`

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 str = "file:///android_asset/dataFrom.html";
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(str);
```

Comment: ccavenue does not provide any api.Hence you cannot pass data or get feedback after a suceessful transaction in your app

Comment: Can you make things more clear here? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: am plan to integrate ccavenue payment gate way for online sales from android app like paypal payment and online payments.